# How do I implement cookie based auth for a Perl website on shared hosting?

Tags: perl, apache, cookies, authentication

I'm very new to Perl, and I have absolutely no idea how to approach this. We have an old Perl application which previously used Apache auth; we'd like to replace this with a cookie based form-style authentication. I understand that this is very case-specific, and there is no one answer as such, but some general tips would be much appreciated.

Will I need to edit all `.pl` files in the website? Or is there a "golden hammer" solution I can use? Is there something on [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org) I can use? We're using Perl v5.8.8 if it matters, and we're using Apache 2 **shared** hosting. I am happy to provide additional information as is necessary.

Comment: Do you use CGI.pm, CGI::Simple or you use some framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers guys, but I eventually decided on [CGI::Session::Auth::DBI](http://search.cpan.org/~geewiz/CGI-Session-Auth-1.06/Auth/DBI.pm) which works well on shared hosting.

Answer (score 1):

For the authentication to be recognized/required, it will need to be checked by the `.pl` file that initially receives the user's request.  So the answer to whether all `.pl` files will need to be changed depends on how your application is structured:

- If the user goes to http://myserver.com/one.pl to do the first thing and http://myserver.com/two.pl to do the second thing, then, yes, you'll need to change them all because they're all receiving requests individually.
- If the user goes to http://myserver.com/dispatch.pl?mode=one for the first thing and http://myserver.com/dispatch.pl?mode=two for the second thing and `dispatch.pl` calls either `one.pl` or `two.pl` behind the scenes based on the `mode` parameter, then you only need to change `dispatch.pl`, since it's the only one directly receiving requests from the user.

**Edited to add:** If you're dealing with the first model, then I'd strongly recommend setting up an external module (`.pm` file) with the cookie-handling code and calling that from each of your individual `.pl` files instead of duplicating that code all over the place.  Ideally, this would let you get by with only a few lines of added code in each `.pl`:

```
use MyCookieHandlingModule qw(verify_cookie redirect_to_login);
my $q = CGI->new;  # ...unless you're already using CGI in object-oriented mode
redirect_to_login unless verify_cookie($q);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it at [a level outside the Perl program](http://authmemcookie.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Depends how much control the host provides (and how much they are willing to do on your behalf)